# CSS formatting not working for table borders

Tags: html, css, web

I was wondering if someone could help me with a CSS related question. The dilemma I am having is that I would like to create a css i guess they are called "classes" for lack of a better word I really don't know what to call them.  But the problem I am having is that for some reason it will only display the borders around one of the tables in my form ill post the code I used to create the tables attributes maybe you can tell me where I am going wrong

```
table.paddedTable table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding-bottom:2px;                    
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 3px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

In the table part I am using `<table class = "paddedTable">`

Comment: Do you mean "table.paddedTable table" or just "table.paddedTable"?

Comment: *"sorry the formatting is off you may have to add new lines its not working with the 4 space indent"* Huh? Really? It's not hard, I've updated it for you. You indent, see, with four spaces. ;-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You can say they are `style definitions` also called `style rules`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would set the borders of any tables contained in a table with class paddedTable.

I think what you want is just:

```
 table.paddedTable  {
border-collapse: collapse;
padding-bottom:2px;                    
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 3px;
height: 100px;
 }
```

However, it would help to see the code in action.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only applies to tables within tables. Try re-writing your selector:

```
 table.paddedTable
 {
border-collapse: collapse;
padding-bottom:2px;                    
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 3px;
height: 100px;
 }
```